# Android OutOfMemoryException in loading a 200kb gif but reallocates 14mb

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide for loading my gif images. It works most of the time but in about multiple calls on different activities(with the former activity always closed with finish()), i sometimes get an OutOfMemoryException while loading the gif that is only 200kb. And the weird part is, the OutOfMemoryException requires to free up 14mb.

here is the oom exception im getting:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte allocation with 13682496 free bytes and 13MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(LayerDrawable.java:388)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:267)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:196)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at com.jian.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: What is your GIF resoulution?

Comment: its resolution is 1400x640

Comment: Probably scale that down.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question why it requires 14mb instead of 200kb

Comment: The footprint in memory of an Image is NEVER equal to Image's file size due to compression. Compressed images cannot be directly show, so the OS should convert them to plain Bitmaps. 200kb for 1400*640 could easily means 3.5MB footprint in memory (1400 * 640 * 4bytes_for_RGBA_pixels). 14MB it's strange. However the Exception was generated starting from an XML Drawable, so maybe you're referring to wrong Image

Comment: It is using GifDrawable by Glide. and nope i have no xml drawable in my app